# How to do a real-time task with a high-load background task in Linux?

Tags: linux, real-time, priority

I've started recording of sound (minor CPU, memory and IO load) as

```
schedtool -R -p 2 -e arecord -f cd > qqq5.wav
```

And perform large compilation (high CPU load + high memory load + high IO load) as this:

```
schedtool -D -e nice -n 19 ionice -c3 make
```

Why does it "overrun!!! (at least -1770319440.252 ms long)" and spoil the recording? Why IDLE_PRIO and idle-io-class dare to mangle tasks with a realtime priority?

How to start heavy-weight thing as *really* low priority? It is allowed to thrash in a swap as it wants, but *without* interfering important things!

P.S. and running out of memory to OOM killer certainly produces "overrun!!!" every time...